# Definable modal logics in first-order structures

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, modal-logic

*The old version didn't ask the right question and was also terribly written; see the edit history if interested. Also: throughout, formulas are allowed parameters, and when I say "definable subset of $D$" for $D$ a definable subset of a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ I mean "definable set in $\mathfrak{A}$ which is a subset of $D$" (as opposed to a definable subset of the substructure induced by $D$).*

---

Suppose we have a first-order structure $\mathfrak{A}$, a formula $\varphi(x,X)$ in the language of $\mathfrak{A}$ together with "$\in$" (where $x$ is an object variable and $X$ is a set variable), and a nonempty definable set $D\subseteq\mathfrak{A}$. The formula $\varphi$ acts on definable subsets of $D$ in a natural way, and this determines a modal logic $L_\mathfrak{A}(\varphi; D)$.

*I'm thinking of a logic as just a set of "validities" here, so "modal logic" just means "set of propositional modal sentences (presumably satisfying some basic closure properties)" - there are definitely situations where this is a bad idea, but for now it's fine.*

Specifically, suppose $v$ is an assignment of definable subsets of $D$ to the propositional atoms $a_i$ ($i\in\mathbb{N}$). To a propositional modal sentence $p$ in these atoms, we recursively assign a subset $v[p]$ of $D$ as follows:

- $v[\top]=D$ and $v[\perp]=\emptyset$.
- If $p=a_i$ then $v[p]=v(a_i)$.
- If $p=r\wedge s$ then $v[p]=v[r]\cap v[s]$.
- If $p=\neg r$ then $v[p]=D\setminus v[r]$.
- If $p=\Diamond r$ then $v[p]=\{a\in D: \mathfrak{A}\models\varphi(a, v[p])\}.$

We then let $L_\mathfrak{A}(\varphi; D)$ be the set of all $p$ such that $v[p]=D$ for every such assignment $v$.

Now let $L(\mathfrak{A})$ be the set of all such logics that can be obtained from $\mathfrak{A}$ in this way. I'm interested in how model-theoretic properties of $\mathfrak{A}$ can affect $L(\mathfrak{A})$. To start with, I'd like to understand $L(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$. This should have some nice extremal property. My knee-jerk instinct was that although countable it should contain all the "reasonably simple" modal logics, but this doesn't seem to stand up to scrutiny: the "possible propositions" here correspond to *arbitrarily complicated* arithmetic formulas, but any specific choice of modality (that is, the $\varphi$) has bounded complexity, so I don't seem to have much leverage after all.

So my question is:

> Is every "logic-like" arithmetically definable set $T$ of propositional modal sentences an element of $L(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$?

By "logic-like" here, I'm addressing the issue that most sets of propositional modal sentences are just silly. I want to restrict attention to ones which are plausible as logics. Specifically, $T$ is logic-like iff:

- $\perp\not\in T$;
- if $p\in T$ and $q$ is gotten by replacing every instance of some propositional atom $a_i$ in $p$ with a propositional formula $r$, then $q\in T$; and
- $T$ is closed under deductions with respect to the usual calculus for propositional *(non-modal)* logic. E.g. if $p,q\in T$ then $p\wedge q\in T$, if $\neg (p\wedge q)\in T$ and $p\in T$ then $\neg q\in T$, etc. - but we don't demand e.g. that if $p\in T$ then $\Diamond p\in T$.

If it would help to strengthen that last bulletpoint (e.g. to closure under deductions in K) I'm interested in that too; but my primary interest right now really is in what we get of we don't place any requirements on how the modality behaves, and just demand that the basic propositional part works as usual.

Comment: A good test case here would be the modal logic GL, since it doesn't have a corresponding first-order frame condition on Kripke frames.

Comment: @James That one's actually pretty easy - as is any modal logic coming from a setup of the type I've described. Abashidze and Blass independently proved that the order topology on $\omega^\omega$ yields GL via Esakia's semantics. But this is appropriately definable in arithmetic: there is a definable linear order $\triangleleft$ of $\mathbb{N}$ of type $\omega^\omega$ and "$x$ is a limit point of $X$ with respect to $\triangleleft$" is clearly definable. Basically, arithmetic does seem "maximally expressive" with respect to modal logics arising from "simple" $(X,\mathcal{W},\mu)$-data as above.

Comment: @James Sorry, that's not quite the whole story - we also need to show that enough subsets of $\omega^\omega$ (appropriately construed) are definable (to show we don't validate anything outside GL). But this isn't hard - again, arithmetic is rich enough to define all the complicated sets we need.

Comment: I guess I don’t really understand the question, but: (1) As long as $\mathcal M$ is nonempty, your logic is consistent, hence it cannot contain the modal formula $\bot$. (2) If the logic $K\oplus\pi$ is consistent, it is valid in a one-element Kripke frame (reflexive or irreflexive). The logic of a one-element frame is “enforceable” in any nonempty structure $\mathcal M$, by taking $\mu(A)=A$ or $\mu(A)=\varnothing$ depending on the reflexivity of the frame. (Also, what does all this has to do with *forcing*?)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek This doesn't have anything to do with forcing - did I suggest that it did? As to the rest of your comment, yeah, it looks like I asked a bit of a stupid question - when I have time I'll reformulate it properly.

Comment: Well, why do you call it *enforceable*, if there is no forcing in sight?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Because I think of the given formula (giving our $\mu$) as "enforcing" a certain behavior. I could have used "guaranteeable," or "ensurable," or ... I don't think the etymological obligation is very strong.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Coming back to this question a couple months later, I've decided it was junk as written and overhauled it. Does this seem better?

Comment: You need more conditions on $T$: $L_{\mathfrak A}(\varphi;D)$ is always closed under the rule $A\leftrightarrow B\mathrel/\Box(A\leftrightarrow B)$.